# How to declare bean as top level which is a requirement in SpringAMQP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-amqp

I have tried creating beans in Spring which were defined in earlier versions of Spring core as `beans.xml`.
SpringAMQP has a requirement to declare `Queue`, `Topic Exchange`, and `Bindings` as a top-level bean. So how should I ensure that in the bean generated would be top-level without the `beans.xml`.

Comment: Every bean in the java-config is a top-level bean, just as they are in xml. So a `<bean .. >` in xml is simply an `@Bean` in java-config.

Comment: @M.Deinum so nested beans would not be declared at all right?

Comment: In Java Config there is no difference in beans so there are only top-level beans and not inner beans.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(...); // or QueueBuilder...
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange exch() {
    return new TopicExchange(...); // or ExchangeBuilder...
}

@Bean
public Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.... // or new Binding(...).
}
```

These must be in a class annotated with `@Confguration`.

Comment: yes, but how can we effectively say that these are top-level beans.
how the `beans.xml` which is defined in Spring is translated here in spring-boot. If you can mention the documentation it would be great.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is, sorry. Where is the confusion coming from? All `@Bean` s are registered by name in the application context. See the [Spring Documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#learn).